# How to use actionsheet showInView method so that it can be shown both in my VC and UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I created a method called ellipses in UIView and this method is creating an actionsheet.I tried to call this method in my UIViewController but it failed because of "[actionSheet showInView:self]".This actionsheet works fine in my view because of 'self' but I dont know how to fix the 'self' so that it can show both in my VC and my View.

here is part of my code in UIView

```
- (void)ellipses{

NSString *deleteButtonName = NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", @"");
NSString *copyButtonName = NSLocalizedString(@"Copy to clipboard", @"");
NSString *cancel = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"");

NSArray *buttons;


buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:deleteButtonName, copyButtonName, nil];


UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

for(NSString *title in buttons)  {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}

[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:cancel];
[actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:[buttons count]];
[actionSheet showInView:self]; // here is gonna be a problem later
}
```

here is part of code in my UIViewController

```
-(void)loadView{
    newView *nView = [newView new];
    [self setView:nView];
    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [testButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 230, 60, 28)];
    [testButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [nView addSubview:testButton];
}

-(void)actionSh{
newView *newview = [[newView alloc] init];
[newview ellipses];//CALL ellipses
[newview setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: What exception are you given when attempting `[actionSheet showInView:self]`?

Comment: I forgot...I have already fixed..Thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer for my question:
add this method in my VC.newView is my UIView.

```
- (newView *) newview {

return (newView *)[self view];
```

}

and call methods from my VC

```
-(void)actionSH {
[[self newview] ellipses];
}
```